# How to combine array from within a variable that has been mapped from an api call

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script

I am trying to return the result of a URLFetchApp API fetch in Google App Script back into Google Sheets using 'sheet.getRange().setValues()'. I can populate individual cells from a variable with one value using the 'setValue()' version however I am stuck when trying to populate multiple cells from an array.

If I 'log(arr)' my variable looks like this,
 
[19-10-12 15:17:45:538 BST] [99]
[19-10-12 15:17:45:669 BST] [98.9]
[19-10-12 15:17:45:829 BST] [91]
[19-10-12 15:17:45:970 BST] [96.4]
[19-10-12 15:17:46:298 BST] [91.6]
[19-10-12 15:17:46:441 BST] [110.6]
[19-10-12 15:17:46:600 BST] [93.7]
[19-10-12 15:17:46:762 BST] [93.8]
[19-10-12 15:17:46:903 BST] [92.6]

I think it should be like this
 [99,98.9,91,96.4,91.6,110.6,93.7,93.8,92.6]

There are lots of detailed guides on using the concat() function to merge variables into one array but I cant find any info how to deal with the incorrect way I have it mapped.

The result is the error 
TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from undefined.
which must be due to my improperly formatted array.

Any help greatly appreciated feel like a right potato at the mo.

```
    var records = results.map(function (positions){

    var position = positions.Metrics.Position;

    var arr = [];

    arr.push(position);

sheet.getRange(6,3,arr.length,arr[0].length).setValues(arr);

    Logger.log(arr)
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're doing please provide more code and some background of what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting a fix to my post. If the answer solved your problem, could you please mark the question as resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I see is that you iterate over the results and write to range for every single record. Let's say your position is 99.

```
var position = positions.Metrics.Position; // === 99
var arr = []; //new empty array
arr.push(position;  // === [99], array with the length of 1.
```

You then go to 6th row 3rd column and attempt to build a range that spans **arr.length** rows down (remember, arr.length equals 1) and **arr[0].length** columns to the right. However, arr[0] equals 99 and the 99 doesn't have a 'length' property (it's undefined!).

```
sheet.getRange(6,3,arr.length,arr[0].length).setValues(arr);
```

Here's the code that might solve your problem:

```
//returns a 2D array where every inner array entry correspons to a row of data
var records = results.map(function(positions){
       return [positions.Metrics.Position];
 });

 sheet.getRange(6,3, records.length, records[0].length).setValues(records);
```